# What happens if I place a charge inside a hollow conductor and fix it?

Tags: electrostatics, symmetry, charge, gauss-law, conductors

So I know that when you put some charge inside a counter, it resides uniformly on the surface of the conductor in order to make the electric field zero everywhere inside the conductor..

But what if I place a charge in such a way that I make it stationary inside the conductor (let it be a spherical conductor), will there be an electric field inside coming out of the charge (assuming its positive) or will something happen to prevent it? And if something happens to prevent it can you please explain to me the process of how it works

The spherical conductor is **hollow** and the charge I put inside it (let's say its in a random place other than the center) is **stationary**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Charge inside conductor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64410/)

Comment: I think mine is a little different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you intend to mean that the free charge is fixed within the conductor. The problem with your reasoning is that the charges within the *conductor* are not fixed. The conductor itself has multiple free charged particles that move to cancel out the electric field within the free space inside the conductor, even if there is free charge inside that is stationary.

To answer your question in slightly more detail, there will briefly be an electric field emanating from the charge inside the spherical conductor, because the charges inherent to the conductor itself move around in order to cancel this field.